# RecyclerView not being populated on back press

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have one activity with 2 fragments (lets call them A and B), each fragment has a recycler view.

I add the fragment by doing

```
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.activity_home_fragment)
this.supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .remove(fragment)
    .add(R.id.activity_home_fragment, newFragment)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit()
```

When I do the forward flow (A -> B) all recyclerviews loaded normally. However, when I go back to the first fragment (B -> A), with the back button, the recycler view doesn't load.

I'm using kotterknife to inject my views

```
val recyclerBuildList by bindView<RecyclerView>(R.id.fragment_build_list_recycler)
```

Following is the code that I'm using to create the adapter:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val build1 = Build()
    build1.id = 3
    build1.name = "Build 1"

    val build2 = Build()
    build2.id = 4
    build2.name = "Build 2"
    val list = arrayListOf(build1, build2)
    setupBuildList(list)
}

private fun setupBuildList(builds: List<Build>) {
    recyclerBuildList.setHasFixedSize(true)
    val adapter = BuildListAdapter(activity, eventBus)
    recyclerBuildList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    adapter.builds = builds
    recyclerBuildList.adapter = adapter
    recyclerBuildList.requestLayout()
}
```

PS.: I'm using Kotlin in my project

I checked in the Hierarchy View and there is nothing inside RecyclerView

Comment: Where are you putting this code? Is this inside of onCreate() or onResume()? I think we're going to need a bit more context.

Comment: Yeah, it really matter where this code is executed. Can you post the full method with this code?

Comment: Added some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/kotterknife/issues/5).

The problem is:

> view properties once created are kept in memory after fragment layout is re-created e.g. screen orientation changes

Comment: Thanks! Used the pull request suggested in the issue and it worked!